# Found a bug in the other person's package. How do tell them to fix

Tags: git, github

I installed this package from github, used it and experienced a bug. I fixed it locally and now I want to tell the guy that he fixes it. How is it done - in terms of github workflow - should I fork or contribute, whatever stuff it is?

Comment: https://guides.github.com/activities/contributing-to-open-source/

Comment: Yes; create your own fork. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209669/github-why-should-i-fork/31219674#31219674 for more details about the workflow.

Answer (score 4):

The standard practice is to:

- Fork the repository
- Create a branch
- Make your changes
- Commit and push your changes
- Submit a pull request

However, how the author wants to handle issues can be different based on repository. Instead of the above, I'd first go to the "Issues" tab on the GitHub repository page and create a new one explaining your bug, and what fix you made to resolve it. The author will most likely point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

You should fork the repository, edit in the changes you made, and do a pull request. That way the author will see your changes and will choose to accept them or not.

Here is some stuff that should get you started if you don't know what to do:

- https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/
- https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/